# Connecting to Remote Host in C (Socket Programming)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, get

My issue is simple: I want to make an HTTP GET request from a server. My client program takes a URL and sends it to the server program. I want to know how I can take this URL and make an HTTP GET request for the specific page that was entered from the client.

If I resolve the URL to get an IP address, I could open a socket to that IP address, but then how would I make the request for the actual page? Would I just send an HTTP GET request directly to that IP address with the directory in the request?

For instance, if I ran a Google search for the word "Test" I'd be presented with the following URL:

https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Test

My understanding is that a GET request could look like this:

```
GET /?gws_rd=ssl#q=Test HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, would I resolve the IP, open a socket, and then just send this GET request directly to the socket?

Lastly, if I try throwing a URL such as the one above into my server code it's unable to resolve an IP address. This means that if I'm making a more complex request than something like www.google.com I'd have to parse the string and match only the host. Is there a simple way to handle this other than by the use of regular expressions? I'm familiar with regular expressions from Python and C#, but if I can cut down on the complexity of the program by approaching this differently, I'd like to know.

Update: I'm attempting to match the URL with a POSIX regular expression and extract the domain name from it. I'm not having much luck so far as this implementation is oppressively confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once a socket has been opened you could send requests as in your example and described in RFC 2616.

If you don't want to use regular expressions or strchr to split your URL you cold also send the entire URL:

`GET http://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Test HTTP/1.1

`

However, you will still need to find the hostname in the URL to make a call to something like `gethostbyname`.